# git, internationalization & iOS string files

Tags: objective-c, ios, git, localization, internationalization

Was wondering whether people here could share their process with internationalization & git. I'm working with an internationalization team which just wants diffs each time we send off our .strings files. Here's what I was thinking in terms of a process:

1. Run genstrings on the codebase to extract all the NSLocalizedStrings. This will generate a .strings file.
2. Diff this .strings file against a previous revision of the same file. This previous revision maps to the last time we sent .strings files off to our internationalization team. So, the diff should contain all the String changes in the project from the last time we sent off the .strings file.
3. Now I have a diff file. Use scripting to alter this diff file to ONLY include the additions and modifications. The output of this script would produce a .strings file. This is the .strings file which our internationalization team wants.
4. After the internationalization process is finished, I'm left with n instances of this .strings file (one for each language). I now need to integrate each of these .strings file back into the project.
5. For each language that I the application supports, take the key and search the original .strings file for the same key. If the key exists in the original .strings file, replace the value in the original .strings file with the value from the diff'ed file. If the key does not exist in the original .strings file, add the new key/value pair to the end of the original .strings file.

Numbers three and five above require some scripting, which leads me to my question.

For number three, is 'git diff' configurable enough to produce a .diff file which ONLY includes the additions or modifications? Does anyone know what the command would look like to ONLY include the additions or modifications? If 'git diff' is not flexible enough to produce the output I need, is anyone aware of some scripting which would produce the desired output.

For number five, is anyone aware of some scripting which already takes care of this?

If someone could suggest a better way of handling the internationalization process for iOS apps, I'm all ears.

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

If you upload your original repo including your English string files then whoever is localizing can fork the project, adjust the strings, commit to their fork and open a pull request. You pull in their changes and merge with your original files. Git/GitHub does all this nasty merging for you.

If the strings are from XIBs then you can use GENStrings again to integrate the new merged string files in your repo with your XIBs.

Rob from Applingua (an app localization agency who works with Git!)

Comment: Unfortunately, the internationalization team that I'm working with are not comfortable with git as it doesnt really work with their current workflow. Thanks all the same.